# Capturing errors with Async/Await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a part of my code that makes several API calls to different endpoints and I want to know if any of those calls fail so I can display an appropriate error message. Right now, if an error happens in `one()` it will stop all other calls from happening, but that's not what I want; If an error occurs, I want it to populate the `errors` object and have the program continue on.

```
async function gatherData() {
    let errors = { one: null, two: null, three: null };

    const responseOne = await one(errors);
    const responseTwo = await two(errors);
    const responseThree = await three(errors);

    if (!_.isNil(errors.one) || !_.isNil(errors.two) || !_.isNil(errors.three)) {
        // an error exists, do something with it
    } else {
        // data is good, do things with responses
    }
}

gatherData();

async function one(errors) {
    await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comment")
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errors.one = err;
            return err;
    });
}

async function two(errors) {
    await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errors.two = err;
            return err;
    });
}

async function three(errors) {
    await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errors.three = err;
            return err;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the `errors` to the `async` functions, so pass the `errors` object as parameter

```
const responseOne = await one(errors);
const responseTwo = await two(errors);
const responseThree = await three(errors);
```

Comment: lol i noticed my own mistake before i could take this question down, but thank you, this is correct

Comment: Actually also this code is pointless `await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then(res => {
            return res;
        }).catch(err => {
            errors.two = err;
            return err;
    });` remove the `await` and `async` if you want to use the `then->catch` concept

Comment: @codtex, could you explain why it's pointless please... for a friend

Comment: Well it is a long story for a comment just do a [**async await vs promise**](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=async+await+vs+promises) google search and read.